# Get active currency and unset countries WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, wpml

I am using WooCommerce with WooCommerce Multilingual.
So I am using different currencies. I want to unset billing and shipping countries based on the current active currency.

I found this function to unset countries:

```
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) {
   unset($country["US"]);
   unset($country["GB"]);

return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```

But I want to change this function so there is conditional logic in it. So for example when `EUR` is the active current currency `US` and `GB` has to be the unset countries. If `GBP` is the current active currency only `US` needs to be unset.

So I found this to get the current active currency:

```
$currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
```

When using this to test it inside a shortcode it gives me the right active currency.

So I rewrote the function:

```
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) {
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
    if ($currency == 'EUR') {
        unset($country["US"]);
        unset($country["GB"]);
    }
    if ($currency == 'GBP') {
        unset($country["US"]);
    }
    return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```

But this doesn't work. It looks like it always takes the way of the if with `EUR` while my currency is `GBP` at that moment.

Comment: I just tested and working fine for me.

Comment: Pretty strange. If U put an `echo` of `$currency` in it it shows you the right active currency?

Comment: try to change a priority.

Comment: I tried different priorities. Which priority did you use to make it work?

Comment: `999` should be work